# Diferencia entre append y write Java

Tags: java, archivo

mi pregunta que se me ha formulado durante que ahora estoy aprendiendo la creación de archivos en Java, mi pregunta es cual es la diferencia entre un append y un write en los archivos en Java, de ser posible poder ejemplificar para poder entender más. Gracias

Comment: ¿Append y write de que Clase? Hay muchas formas de escribir archivos en Java.

Comment: Append añade a lo existente digamos, write sobreescribe, asi a grandes rasgos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que investigaste hasta ahora? buscaste algo por internet?